# How to classify a resume segments in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, text-classification

I need to apply deep learning in resume analysis, by taking the text and split it into paragraphs, then pass each paragraph into a deep learning model that predicts if this paragraph is skills, education, experience, etc. So we can call it is a `multi-label classification` problem.

By the way, I have a dataset that contains paragraphs and its labels!

Can I perform that with `text classification` in Keras? Which model I can use and what will be the necessary steps in text pre-processing?

I am pretty new to this field. Thanks in advance!